# tkinter display an image according to a key entered in entry field

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to display different images according to a key entered into a tinter entry field. I am returning None from my function to search through the dictionary that holds as key the search word and as value the name of the image. I am not sure how to correct my error. My ultimate goal is to create a tinter GUI that is an 'illustrative' dictionary' Grateful for any help or comments
    '''
    Example how to place text and image adjacent in a field
    '''
    from tkinter import *

```
def choose_image():
    library = {'anchor':'admiral.gif', 'hello':'hello_tkinter_cartoon.gif'}
    term = e.get()
    for desc, image in library.items():
        if term == desc:
            piccie = image
            return desc, piccie

main = Tk()

# enter search key
e = StringVar()
term_entry = Entry( textvariable = e, bd = 2, width = 15, bg = 'mint cream', fg = 'sea green')
term_entry.grid(row =1, column =0, sticky = SE, pady = 15)

butn = Button(text = "Enter",)
butn.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = W)

piccie = choose_image()
print(piccie)
piccie = PhotoImage(file=piccie)
desc = choose_image()
# two results fields adjacent

w1 = Label(main, image =piccie).grid(column = 1, row =0)
w2 = Label(main,
           text = desc,
           justify=LEFT,
           padx = 10).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `None` because that's the default return value that any function in Python returns.

The first time you call `choose_image()`, `e.get()` returns an *empty string*, thus the following code:

```
piccie = image
return desc, piccie
```

will not be executed, because `term == desc` will not be true.

You can solve this problem for example by returning a default tuple of values when the `e.get()` returns an empty string:

```
library = {'anchor':'admiral.gif', 'hello':'hello.gif'}
term = e.get()

if term == "":
    return "anchor", "admiral.gif"
```

Note that in this same function the `piccie` variable is a local variable to the `if` block, and not your global variable references a `PhotoImage` object. On the other hand, you are returning a tuple containing the path to the picture, which should be enough to set the `PhotoImage` object.

Your second problem is that you are assigning to the attribute `file` of your `PhotoImage` object an eventual tuple of strings, but it should only need a string representing the path to the picture:

```
piccie = choose_image()
piccie = PhotoImage(file=piccie[1])
```

Note that I am assigning to the `file` attribute the second element of the tuple.

I don't understand why you are calling the second time `choose_image()`, you don't need to do it.

Here's the full code with some changes. If you don't understand something, just ask.

```
from tkinter import *


def choose_image(photo_image, text_lab, image_lab):
    library = {'anchor':'admiral.gif', 'hello': 'hello.gif'}
    term = e.get()

    if term == "":
        photo_image.config(file="admiral.gif")
        text_lab.config(text="anchor")
        image_lab.config(image=photo_image)
    else:
        for desc, image in library.items():
            if term == desc:
                photo_image.config(file=image)
                text_lab.config(text=desc)
                image_lab.config(image=photo_image)

main = Tk()

e = StringVar()
term_entry = Entry(textvariable=e, bd=2, width = 15, bg='mint cream', fg='sea green')
term_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=SE, pady=15)

label_text = Label(main)
label_text.grid(column=1, row=0)

label_image = Label(main, justify=LEFT, padx=10)
label_image.grid(row=0, column=0)

photo_image = PhotoImage(file="admiral.gif")

choose_image(photo_image, label_text, label_image)

butn = Button(text="Enter", command=lambda: choose_image(photo_image, label_text, label_image))
butn.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

main.mainloop()
```

Check also this article:

> http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your logic. If I were to want a more extensive description than simply using the key from the dictionary, I suppose that I should make the value of the dictionary a tuple containing caption and image and then reference them accordingly. Would this be the correct approach?

Comment: Thank you for this. Works perfectly also having the value of the key as a tuple containing a caption and the image.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling `choose_image()` before the user has a chance to enter anything. You need to wait to call that function until the user has entered something and pressed the enter key, or clicked a button, or something like that.